# How to display text from object array in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Seems like it'd be pretty straight forward but I am not able to get my text to display

In my HTML I have `<td>{{cabinetDetails.cabinetType}}</td>` and my data source is `$scope.cabinetDetails = [{cabinetType: 'panel'}];`

Nothing is displaying in my HTML. I've also tried: `$scope.cabinetDetails = [{'cabinetType': 'panel'}];`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you have made an array of objects, so I think the code that would currently work is either:

```
<td>{{cabinetDetails[0].cabinetType}}</td>
```

Or replace

```
$scope.cabinetDetails = [{cabinetType: 'panel'}];
```

with

```
$scope.cabinetDetails = {cabinetType: 'panel'};
```

Comment: Ahh duh. Ok I spaced on that. I'm going to do that last snippet. I'll accept you answer in 10 minutes

Comment: Good choice, because unless you plan on adding more objects to that array in the future, just use a plain object.

Comment: I definitely plan on adding more so that would be the wiser choice.